# How to pass values to a publisher in ROS?

Tags: python, publish-subscribe, ros

I am currently trying to write a Python ROS program which can be executed as a ROS node (using rosrun) that implements the defs declared in a separate Python file arm.py (available at: https://github.com/nortega1/dvrk-ros/blob/44c8604b6c120e91f5357e7fd3649a8f7936c504/dvrk_python/src/dvrk/arm.py). The program initially examines the current cartesian position of the arm. Subsequently, when provided with a series of points that the arm must pass through, the program calculates a polynomial equation and given a range of x values the program evaluates the equation to find the corresponding y values.

Within the `arm.py` file there is a publisher `set_position_cartesian_pub` that sets the Cartesian position of the arm as follows:

```
self.__set_position_cartesian_pub = rospy.Publisher(self.__full_ros_namespace + '/set_position_cartesian', Pose, latch = True, queue_size = 1)
```

However, I am unsure how to pass the x and y values (I'll calculate the z values at a later date) to the publisher in the python program that I am creating. This is what I have written thus far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
from tf import transformations
from tf_conversions import posemath
from std_msgs.msg import String, Bool, Float32, Empty, Float64MultiArray
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose, PoseStamped, Vector3, Quaternion, Wrench, WrenchStamped, TwistStamped

def callback(data):
  rospy.loginfo(data.pose)

def currentPositionListener():
    rospy.init_node('currentPositionListener', anonymous=True)
    rospy.Subscriber('/dvrk/PSM1/position_cartesian_current', PoseStamped, callback)
    rospy.spin()

def lagrange(f, x):
    total = 0
    n = len(f)
    for i in range(n):
        xi, yi = f[i]

        def g(i, n):
            g_tot = 1
            for j in range(n):
                if i == j:
                    continue
                xj, yj = f[j]
                g_tot *= (x - xj) / float(xi - xj)

            return g_tot

        total += yi * g(i, n)
    return total

def newPositionListener():
    rospy.Subscriber('/dvrk/PSM1/set_position_cartesian', PoseStamped, trajectoryMover)
    rospy.spin()

def trajectoryMover(data):
    points =[(0,0),(45,30),(23,10), (48,0)]
    xlist = [i for i in range(100)]
    ylist = [lagrange(points, xlist[i]) for i in range(100)]
    for x, y in zip(xlist, ylist):
        data.pose.x = x
        data.pose.y = y
        data.pose.z = 0

if __name__ == '__main__':
    currentPositionListener()
    newPositionListener()
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in `.trajectoryMover()`:

If you want to publish a `Pose` message you should create a `Pose` message and fill in its positions like below code snippet:

```
from geometry_msgs.msg import Pose


def trajectoryMover(data):
    pose = Pose()
    self.__set_position_cartesian_pub = rospy.Publisher(
        self.__full_ros_namespace + '/set_position_cartesian',
        Pose, latch = True, queue_size = 1
    )

    points =[(0,0),(45,30),(23,10), (48,0)]
    xlist = [i for i in range(100)]
    ylist = [lagrange(points, xlist[i]) for i in range(100)]
    for x, y in zip(xlist, ylist):
        pose.x = x
        pose.y = y
        pose.z = 0
        self.__set_position_cartesian_pub.publish(pose)
```

---

[**NOTE**]:

- A `.spin()` is enough for your code.
- I couldn't realize what is data you need for.